# Can an AIR application access its own digital signature?

Tags: flash, air

All AIR installation files must be digitally signed ([http://help.adobe.com/...](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappsflex/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7fd8.html)).
Is there a way for an AIR application to access this signature information at runtime?

Say, I'm distributing client-side component of a client-server application,
and this client component is implemented using AIR,
and I want to prevent* modified copies of the client from accessing the server.
Then I could do that by letting the server check the digital signature of the client.

(* of course, this is by no means provides a full guarantee,
as it is always possible to re-implement the client-server protocol,
but let's consider the simplest case)

Answer (score 1):

Why? I assume you are doign this to prevent piracy? If so, I think you should reconsider the value of doing this. If your users are modifying your application in order to crack it, they can also modify it to send a "valid" signature back to your server. Your time would almost certainly be better spent adding features that your users *want* to pay for.

Comment: Consider a typical multi-player game. A modification of the client may result in unfair competition between players. In this situation, preventing modification of the client by some users is actually a useful feature for other users.

Comment: If they can modify the client to cheat, they can cheat the signature too. You can spend all your time in a never-ending arms war with the cheaters, or you can add new features to please your legitimate users and use moderators to ban obvious cheaters.

Comment: Thank you for advising me how should I spend my time.
Now could you please answer my question regarding the AIR API?
Thank you in advance.